# Taxonomy / Category

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have created Taxonomy with the reference 
http://www.anilsagar.com/content/drupal-7-tutorial-part-13-drupal-7-taxonomy-vocabulary-terms-tags-categories-concepts .

How to call this in the template file.. Please explain about taxonomy, that is what type of situations we can you taxomomy.. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of taxonomy

[image]

When we click on the link it will lead us to all questions under the tag/term.

In Bartik there is taxonomy visible in teaser and full modes. 
Enable the theme and check your content.

Why youre looking for templates ?

Comment: There is a disabled view named "Taxonomy term" enable it and check the page.